# How can I stop Time Machine from backing up on battery when "Backup while on battery power" is UNCHECKED?

Tags: time-machine, catalina, battery

Hopefully the title explains everything. I just noticed that Time Machine is currently backing up, although the preference to "Backup while on battery power" is clearly unchecked.

How can I fix this?